# Oracle db with localhost

Tags: oracle11g

I am using oracle db for the first time and I have prior experience using MYSQL. I am super confused with the installation process. My main doubt is can I connect to a localhost using Oracle db like how I do for MySQL, as I don't have a oracle server to connect. If so, what might the process?

Comment: If you want to connect to an Oracle database you need a database adm program. I recommend Toad for Oracle.

Comment: You have to install a local server in MySQL as well as in Oracle. Oracle comes with a graphical installer that enables you to install it on "localhost". And in both cases you need to start that server locally in order to be _able_ to connect.

Comment: You need a few things. Please provide more information. Linux? Windows? What have you done so far? Have you read the official installation guides? You need to setup a client + PHP library (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)

Comment: download the zips of the DB from the Oracle homepage, install it, and install SQL Developer too (this is a GUI for Oracle database). With the Developer you can access the DB

Answer (score 1):

Steps to run oracle db

1. You should first install oracle db on your laptop/pc.
2. Then you install SQL developer tool which is like MySQL Workbench
3. In Step 1 while installing the db, remember the username and password which you may have to enter during the step 2
4. Once you install the sql developer tool, then you connect to the database.

For installing database - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_CyuCLC3Ls

For installing sql developer tool - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSr7oVOkR6w

Answer (score 0):

you can connect to a localhost using Oracle Database, just like you do for MySQL. If you don't have an Oracle server to connect to, you can install the Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) on your local computer. Once you have installed XE, you can connect to it